# Artifact placing improvements on lanes

Tags: artifact

Does it matter which lane I put my improvement in?

For example in this game I put my iron fog in the hard lane that i'm probably going to lose. Is it more likely to get destroyed in that lane vs any other lane?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking about it more I've come to conclude that it matters and mid was the wrong place for the iron fog. The best lane is probably the right lane.

- You want to avoid red lanes to play around Smash Their Defenses! This means mid is probably the worst lane.
- In that specific game it probably shouldn't be the left lane as that lane already had the combat phase and you would miss out on 3 gold.
- You also want to play around Demagicking Maul, which is a highly relevant and great item. The lane that you're not going to lose is the safest place for it. If you're not sure which lane that is then just go by the first two criteria. I put this as the final criteria as it's the hardest one to play around at the start of the game, but it might be the most relevant criteria mid way through the game, or if they already have a maul equipped.

Yes this only applies to non combat relevant improvements, other improvements should go into more contested lanes.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No, it doesn't matter which lane you put it in, with respect to the chances it'll get destroyed.
Long answer: See below.

Iron fog is an improvement, and improvements are neither units nor spells and hence do not occupy combat positions, so you can technically put them anywhere.

Currently, improvements can only be destroyed by effects which destroy improvements - specifically [Condemn](https://artifact.gamepedia.com/Condemn), which effects (regarding improvements) range from destroying a specific improvement, all enemy improvements or random improvements. Notice that there is no effect to the likes of 'destroy improvement applied on Mid lane', or '80% chance of destroying improvement on Mid, 20% for other lanes' etc, so the lane it is applied on does not affect the chances of it getting destroyed.

However, this answer only applies to Iron Fog as an improvement, and the chance of it getting destroyed. There are other improvements which may require an allied hero on the lane or effect on a tower on that lane, which you would want to strategize on where to put those depending on whether you want to snowball a winning lane or save a losing lane.

Also, an anti-improvement deploying improvement such as [Watchtower](https://artifact.gamepedia.com/Watchtower) would be a high priority target of destruction for an opponent wanting to use their improvement to contest the lane, so you could argue that the lane it gets deployed to matters as to the chance the opponent will destroy it.